# My recorded voice will be heard to caller in android

Tags: android, android-intent

i want to play a recorded voice when the caller calls in android. is it possible to play a audio stream rather then the usual beep or tone when caller calls in android? actually is it possible to control in call audio stream???

Comment: Is this even a programming question? If it is, you'll need to add a **lot** more detail.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot play arbitrary audio over the call stream. Infact, Android allows no access to the call stream at all, read or write.

Call audio is handled at a hardware level much lower than the SDK, and for security reasons recording and playing of audio isn't allowed.

Answer (score 0):

First, no it isn't-- not the way you want to do it, the voice message they hear is controlled by your voicemail service provider (usually your cell provider).

Second, this forum is for programming questions and this question doesn't belong here.